# SELECT multiple rows and concatenate into one - in joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a problem selecting multiple rows and retrieving them as one row. The problem is that Joomla stores data from the userprofile in two columns called profile_key and profile_value. I would like to retrieve all the rows from the column 'profile_key' named 'profile.li_vid', 'profile.li_kre' corresponding to the column 'profile_value' where the values are "1".

DB draft

```
user_id | profile_key        | profile_value
475     | profile.li_vid     | "1"
475     | profile.li_kre     | "1"
475     | profile.address1   | "1"
476     | profile.li_vid     | "1"
476     | profile.li_kre     | "1"
476     | profile.address1   | "1"
```

Code

```
  $db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select ($db->quoteName(array('a.id','a.name', 'b.profile_value','b.profile_key')))
        ->from ($db->quoteName('#__users','a'))
        ->where ($db->quoteName('b.profile_key') . " = " . $db->quote('profile.li%'))

        // ->where ($db->quote('profile_value') . " = \"1\" " )
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__user_profiles','b').'ON('.$db->quoteName('a.id').'='.$db->quoteName('b.user_id').')')
        ->order($db->quoteName('a.name').'ASC')
     ;
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
```

When I echo them to the screen in a foreach loop, they appear in separate rows in my table because the code loops through every query result row by row. I thought of a solution where I concatenate multiple rows into one - but how?
I hope you are able to help me out.

Comment: You can use mysqls `GROUP_CONCAT` I'm not sure how to do it in Joomla though.

Comment: Yes - I've tried but recieves an error when I put it in my SELECT line - L

Comment: Can you post your query in plain SQL? Then I'm able to help you.

Comment: Thanks Daan - yes in plain SQL it's possible - but within Joomla i'm in trouble! But thank You for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: GROUP_CONCAT() has a char limit of 1024 by default!